# Getting out the xPos and YPos valueses from a arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

I have this java class:

```
public class Coordinate {

    //Instansvariabler (klassvariabler, objektvariabler)
    int xPos, yPos;

    //Konstruktor
    public Coordinate(int xPos, int yPos){
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

}
```

And i am using a ArrayList to get as many values as i need with this for-loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < snakeParts; i++){
            if(snake.size() <= snakeParts)
            snake.add(new Coordinate(0, 0));
        }
```

How can i get the xPos and yPos from snake.get(i)? Is there any simple way of doing this? When i print snake.get(i) this is what i get: Coordinate@634b392;

Comment: override method `toString` in class `Coordinate` to return its instances in any format you wish.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I'm very new to programming so I'm not 100% sure what you mean, how would I do that?

Comment: In Java when an object is printed, it's method `toString` is called, and `Coordinate@634b392` is returned by default implementation of `toString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a getter in class `Coordinate`:

```
public int getX() {
    return xPos;
}
```

then, you can get it via: `snake.get(i).getX();`. Also add a toString so that printing your coordinate prints something more useful.

If you want to simplify this stuff, your IDE can generate it for you, or, use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).